# Stopping a connection being faked?

Tags: php, encryption

Well I am desiging an anti-cheat for the game combat arms.
What i want to do is 'ping' the program with the database so that people cannot simply create a program that makes it seem as though they are using the anti-cheat.

Is there a way to 'encrypt' or stop other people simulating the connection easily?
I am not great with PHP and this is how it adds it so far:

```
public function Update()
    {
        $ign = $_GET['ign'];
        $timestamp = $_GET['uid'];
        $time = time();

        if(($time - 10 < $timestamp) && ($time + 10 > $timestamp))
        {
            $this->connection();
            $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE ign = '{$ign}'");
            if(mysql_num_rows($data) > 0)
            {
                mysql_query("UPDATE users SET lastonline = '{$time}' WHERE ign = '{$ign}'");
            }
            else
            {
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (id, ign, lastonline) VALUES ( NULL, '{$ign}', '{$time}' ) ");
            }

            echo "Connected to database";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Problem connecting";
        }
    }
```

I need some sort of way to protect it/make it hard to crack quickly.
And once cracked I can easily change, hope this has provided enough information!

Comment: Protecting games against fraud is a very complex undertaking. It's not as easy as inserting a couple lines here or there.

Comment: See e.g. [What is the best way to stop people hacking the PHP-based highscore table of a Flash game](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73947/what-is-the-best-way-to-stop-people-hacking-the-php-based-highscore-table-of-a-f)

Comment: Also, what if my IGN is `x OR 1 == 1` and I get *everyone in the game banned*?

Comment: Cheats are the least of your worries. How about protecting your data from SQL injections!

Comment: The game has terrible protection, we are making a third party program to improve that
@Bart D: where is it vul?

Comment: @Cacoon: `$ign = $_GET['ign'];`. You're not even sanitizing. Later on, you're injecting that *raw* into a query. Do you expect people to play fair?

Comment: Is there any point? Really... I mean at the end of the day games are always being hacked. You can't stop people hacking them indefinitely because someone will always find a break in the code and exploit it.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it's pretty much mandatory here that you sanitize your SQL input. I recommend using a prepare with PDO (`ext/mysql` is [going on a journey far, far away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)).

```
$db = new PDO(<connection details>);
$prepare = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE ign = :ign");
// Tip: make sure you actually check the prepare worked before trying to execute.
$prepare->execute(array(":ign" => $ign));
```

And so on. Read the [reference manual](http://php.net/pdo).

However if you are using mysql_* and refuse to change (though if you update PHP to 5.5 when it releases, you'll have `E_DEPRECATED` thrown), use `mysql_real_escape_string` and drop the quotes in the queries.

---

Next, onto actually handling the requests.

There's several ways to do this, but the most secure (and only option you should take) would be something cryptographically strong, such as a One Time Pad, or OAuth.

Generate credentials, and make the game send a token signed with a hash that is uniquely generated, perhaps from a product code. This should be unique for every installation and should generate hashes that are able to be validated by the script.

This is a problem that is constantly being researched by games companies, but it's often for naught; Your game can and will be reverse engineered by anyone who feels it's worthy of their time to do so. As will the Anti-Cheat.

---

Nevertheless, sign a request and include:

- The player's in-game name
- A very accurate timestamp which can be verified in some way.
- Request signature (Cryptographically Secure)
- Location Data (Useful for banning speedhackers, but be careful for false positives if someone teleports, etc)
- Anything else required by the Anti-Cheat (You will likely have a specification for this)

Also, for the love of gaming, don't do a Punkbuster-style anti-cheat (aka *don't ban on a request in a botnet-style fashion; it can be abused* <sub>[source](http://privacy-pc.com/news/hacking-online-games-josh-phillips-and-michael-donnelly-at-defcon-19-part-3.html)</sub>
)

Finally, I'd probably recommend getting a professional security researcher in to review everything.