# Avoid pausing flash game with cheat-engine by pausing the browser process

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

For a flash game i'm working on i would like to know if there is anything that can be done to stop players that pause the game by pausing the browser process as shown in [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6v7YV_O-m5w) youtube video?

I'm already looking in to all the other great suggestions to avoid or at least slow down cheat engine hackers at : [What is the best way to stop people hacking the PHP-based highscore table of a Flash game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73947/what-is-the-best-way-to-stop-people-hacking-the-php-based-highscore-table-of-a-f?answertab=active#tab-top). But couldn't find anything on pausing processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pausing a process is detectable by using `(new Date()).getTime()` repeatedly with short intervals. If, say, the difference between the dates exceeds several seconds, and you are querying this statement once per 30 frames, then either your framerate stalls or the process has been paused.